# Migration between 2 Nexus3 instances

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I would like to migrate all the data from a OSS Nexus 3.19.1-01 to a Nexus 3.25.1-04 without service interruption (impossible to shutdown the Nexus 3.19 during the procedure)

I only find procedures for migrating from Nexus2 to Nexus3 and apparently the import/export solution will only work from 3.24 versions. Additionally it seems that this is only applicable to Nexus PRO versions: [Link](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/system-configuration/tasks/repository-export#RepositoryExport-SupportedFormats)

The formats I need to migrate are: Maven2, docker, yum, raw, npm and nuget.

Is there any official procedure for performing this task?

Another ideas? Maybe API?

Comment: Why "without service interruption"? That doesn't make much sense to me. Just close the dependent services if they can't handle it and inform the users....

Answer (score 0):

Check the links below, it might help you. But in all cases they recommend to shutdown Nexus so you don't have to deal with any integrity issues.

https://community.sonatype.com/t/nexus-to-nexus-migration/3608/3

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010352014-Moving-a-Nexus-Repo-3-Installation-to-a-New-Location